# Magento 2: Configurable product dropdown attributes on category listing page

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, dropdown-attribute, category-listing

I am looking for an option to get the configurable product attributes with each product on category listing page.

Magento 2 defaults to swatches only. How can we change it to dropdown?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This All depends if your looking to have swatches or dropdowns the answer for dropdowns is not so easy.

First create a custom module.  And add the following to your di, file this class stops configurable products getting the correct add to cart.

```xml
<type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="remove_possible_by_from_list" type="GremlinTech\CategoryConfigurable\Plugin\Configurable" sortOrder="1"  disabled="false"/>

</type>
```

Then create a custom php class Under  Plugin called configurable

```php
<?php

namespace GremlinTech\CategoryConfigurable\Plugin;

class Configurable
{

    public function afterIsPossibleBuyFromList(\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $subject, $result)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Next step is to overwrite the Magento_Catalog::templates/list.phtml and add the following under the hidden input fields that are already there.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="item"  value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>" />
```

Also you need to modify the form element itself to look like below

```html
      <form data-role="tocart-form"
                      id="product_addtocart_form-<?=$_product->getId(); ?>"
                      data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                      action="<?= $block->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>"
                      <?php if ($_product->getOptions()) :?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>
                      method="post">
```

Now your list view has its actual fields, you need to add a catalog_category_view.xml layout either in the theme or in the module created above, and add the following. This will call the product view configurable template into your list.

```xml
  <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="category.product.configurable" as="configurable_options"  template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/view/type/options/configurable.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

You will need to do the same for catalogsearch_result_index.xml as the xml is different for search results though uses the same catalog list template

```xml
 <referenceBlock name="search_result_list">
            <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="category.product.configurable" as="configurable_options"  template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/view/type/options/configurable.phtml" />
 </referenceBlock>
```

Now we have this you need to overide the Magento_Catalog::product/list/view/type/options/configurable.phtml template again in the theme or module, you then need to make it look like the below.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>

<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable*/
$_product    = $block->getProduct();
if($_product->getTypeId() === 'configurable') :
$_attributes = $block->decorateArray($block->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)) :?>
    <?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute) : ?>
        <div class="field configurable required">
            <label class="label" for="attribute<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_attribute->getAttributeId()) ?>">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel()) ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_attribute->getAttributeId()) ?>]"
                        data-selector="super_attribute[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_attribute->getAttributeId()) ?>]"
                        data-validate="{required:true}"
                        id="attribute<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_attribute->getAttributeId()) ?>"
                        class="super-attribute-select">
                    <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Choose an Option...')) ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=priceBox][data-price-box=product-id-<?= $block->escapeJs($_product->getId()) ?>]": {
                "priceBox": {}
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form-<?=$_product->getId(); ?>": {
                "configurable": {
                    "selectSimpleProduct" : ".cart-price.product-<?=$_product->getId(); ?> [name=selected_configurable_option]",
                    "priceHolderSelector" : ".cart-price.product-<?=$_product->getId(); ?> > .price-box",
                    "spConfig": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>,
                    "gallerySwitchStrategy": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->getVar(
                        'gallery_switch_strategy',
                        'Magento_ConfigurableProduct'
                    ) ?: 'replace'); ?>"
                }
            },
            "*" : {
                "Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/catalog-add-to-cart": {}
            }
        }
    </script>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

What has changed from default configurable.phtml

We added the below init script this makes the prices dynamic on the grid itself, without the below prices fail to inizalize and configurable options with static prices would fail.

```php
 <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=priceBox][data-price-box=product-id-<?= $block->escapeJs($_product->getId()) ?>]": {
                "priceBox": {}
            }
        }
    </script>
```

We have also modified the paramatersin the configurable x-init to make them more specific to the grid inidviual items otherwise all prices would change on each item and so would the hidden configurable_selected hidden item.

Final Thing to do is to call the options in the loop  in your list.phtml again, within the scope of the form,

```php
  <?= $block->getChildBlock("configurable_options")->setData('product', $_product)->toHtml(); ?>
```

What we are doing is getting our child block and setting the specific list item as the product on the block otherwise it would try and use the registry like it does on product view.

Thats it hope this helps.

Comment: if there are multiple configurable products in the listing then dropdown is getting field for only first product.rest are show disabled

Comment: Error: Call to a member function setData() on bool this error fetch any idea.

Comment: @SairajGadekar is there any solution to resolve this issue? I too face it when more than one configurable dropdown then I received this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at $.<computed>.<computed>._getSimpleProductId (configurable.js:657)